# Get a list of API Names of all Fields for an Object.

Tags: salesforce, schema, apex-code

Is it possible to get a list of all API Names for all fields on an object?

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r =Object__c.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
for(Schema.DescribeSObjectResult result : r){
   apiNames.add();   //this is where I am lost. 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [fields](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_fields) method to get the Schema.SObjectTypeFields.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<String>apiNames =  new list<String>();
for(string apiName : r.fields.getMap().keySet()){
   apiNames.add(apiName);
}
System.debug(apiNames);
```